# How to change composer version in windows 10

Tags: composer-php

I use composer version 2 but I want to use v1 now
Please help me.
[image]

Comment: You want to downgrade your installation of composer?

Comment: yes, I want to downgrade this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not fix the listed problem instead?

Answer (score -2):

I think this is impossible, because composer download his up to date version everytime.

I think there is not answer correct and I need to know why you want to change version.

Comment: Why should that be impossible? Without using the self-update feature, Composer will not update itself, and old releases are present at least on Github